# Creating progress bar for file upload and moving it to Amazon server

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am working on image upload functionality in PHP where i will show the upload progress bar using **`swfuploader`** while uploading. But the problem is after uploading the image, i am creating some thumbnail of the image uploaded(which will take some negotiable time) and moving the original image to Amazon server. But the progress bar showing is only for uploading to our server and not for uploading  to amazon server. What i need is a way to show the progress bar which should includes the moving of the image to *Amazon server* also. Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not think this is possible. You can simply display the status "sent to the Amazon"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pipe Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) will let you monitor the progress of almost any process.

From that you can feed the progress into a display of your choice, I'd suggest [jQuery Progress Bar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar) as it is very versatile, easy to set up and has plenty of example tutorials in case you get stuck